# Android Media Player issue with emulator when playing .mp4 on small screens

Tags: android, video, android-emulator

i am using a MediaPlayer for my **Android** app to play an .mp4 video.

In my code i have *minimumSDK API16*, so when i am testing my app the video is playing on real devices that i have tested until now (Samsung galaxy S7, Note 3, AcerT01, Nexus 5) but unfortunately i don't have any older device to test it (Jelly Bean).

When i test on emulator with *Nexus 5, Nexus 6, Nexus ONE* the video loads successfully, **BUT** when i test on smaller screen *2.7" QVGA_API22* the **emulator** doen't load the video and i got the message: ***Can't play this video*** and also i check the *Logcat* and i got the following error:

> E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   AnimationScreenActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2c8dbe92
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-240,108}

So my question is that is it just an emulator issue or is something wrong with the Android Media Player and screen size?

EDIT:

Here is a part of my code:

```
VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.introphonescreen);
videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);    
videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        jump();
    }
});

private void jump() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (MainActivity.SPLASH_LOCK) {
                    // wait for notify or time-out
                    try {
                        MainActivity.SPLASH_LOCK.wait(MAX_SPLASH_TIME);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
                }
                finish();
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Comment: Any media player errors, like this "MediaPlayer: Error (-4,-4)"?

Comment: Yes, i have: 
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)

Comment: Can you post code snippet where you init MediaPlayer and start playing?

Comment: Also you can take a look on [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Comment: @Ufkoku I edited my question with a part of my code

Comment: Are you using onPrepared() callback from MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, before calling videoView.start()?

Comment: @Ufkoku No i am not using onPrepared() at all. I tried it but it didn't change anything.. And when i used it, once the web page was loaded, it stops the video immediately (doesn't wait for the video to complete and then load my webpage).

Comment: @Ufkoku The problem appears only when i am using the Android Emulator 2.7" QVGA with the message: Can't play this video.

But i am wondering if this is an emulator issue since i don't have access to a real device now with small screen so i can check, because when i check on larger phones (Galaxy S7, Nexus 5) it works fine.

Comment: There is a limit for max texture size on devices. I know, that it limits max bitmap size, that can be drawn at ImageView. Maybe it also affects max video resolution too? You can get max texture size by this [code](https://github.com/Ufkoku/PicassoExtensions/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/com/ufkoku/utils/GLUtils.java).

Comment: @Ufkoku can you elaborate more about this code and how to use it in my code?

Comment: you can get max size and log it on working device and not. If on not working device video resolution > max available, and on working devices video resolution <= max available. Than it is the cause of problem.